# How do you only run a validator on a form field at the end after no validation errors have been raised?

Tags: django, django-forms

I would like to only run a specific checksum validation if things like required, min and max validations as well as a custom `is_digit()` validation is run.

The reason is I do not want to show the error message for the checksum validation if some other validation is failing.

I've tried:

```
id_number = ZaIdField(
    required=False,
    max_length=13,
    min_length=13,
    validators=[validate_numeric, ]
)
```

then I have the checksum validator after others run in `super()`:

```
class ZaIdField(forms.CharField):
    '''
    Field for validating ZA Id Numbers
    '''
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def validate(self, value):
        """Check if id is valid"""
        # Use the parent's handling of required fields, etc.
        super().validate(value)
        validate_sa_id(value)
```

Update:

In other words, my final validation is dependent on the length being correct and all digits.
So I just want to ensure that is correct before running it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has probably been answered somewhere before but it looks like the right palce to do this is in the form's `clean()`:

```
def clean(self):
    cleaned_data = super().clean()
    id_num = cleaned_data.get('id_number')
    if id_num:
        validate_sa_id(id_num)
    return cleaned_data
```

The key part of the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other) is:

> By the time the form’s clean() method is called, all the individual
>   field clean methods will have been run (the previous two sections), so
>   self.cleaned_data will be populated with any data that has survived so
>   far.

So you just check if the field has survived, if it has then it has passed prior validations

Answer (score 0):

Check the [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/forms/validation/) for more information. It's pretty simple actually.

```
def clean_id_number(self):
    data = self.cleaned_data['id_number']

    if checksum:
        raise forms.ValidationError("Checksum error!")

    return data
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to mess with the order of the validators, I would override the `ZaIdFields`[`run_validators`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/fields.py#L129) method.

Note that the fields `validate` method that you're overriding will always be [called before](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/).

Example (untested):

```
class ZaIdField(forms.CharField):
    '''
    Field for validating ZA Id Numbers
    '''

    def run_validators(self, value):
        super().run_validators(value)  # will potentially throw ValidationError, exiting

        validate_sa_id(value)  # your late validator, will throw its own ValidationError
```

Comment: Alright so that makes it run last but it still runs, from my tests. How can I not run it if there are errors?